# Should you recreate containers when deploying web app?

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, docker

I'm trying to figure out if best practices would dictate that when deploying a new version of my web app (nodejs running in its own container) I should:

- Do a `git pull` from inside the container and update "in place"; or
- Create a new container with the new code and perform a hot swap of the two docker containers

I may be missing some technical details as I'm very new to the idea of containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is the best practice: you would make a second version of your image (with the new code), stop your container, and run a second container based on that second version.

The idea is that you can easily roll-back as the first version of your image can be used to run the container that was initially in production at any time.

Trying to modify a running container is not a good idea as, once it is stopped and removed, running it again would be from the original image, with its original state. Unless you commit that container to a new image, those changes would be lost. And even if you did commit, you would not be able to easily rebuild that image. (plus you would commit the all container: its new code, but also a bunch of additional files created during the execution of the server: logs and other files: not very clean)

A container is supposed to be run from an image that you can precisely build from the [specifications of a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/). It is not supposed to be modified at runtime.

Couple of caveat though:

- if your container [is used (`--link`) by other containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links), you would beed to stop those first, stop your container and run a new one from a new version of the image, then restart your other containers.
- don't forget to remount any **[data containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)** that you were using in order to get your persistent data.